# error trying to recycle app pools with a vbscript

Tags: wmi

Can any one tell me why I am getting an error message with this code:
I am trying to recycle app pools with a wmi script

Line that errors is "set objWMIService ..."

Error message is "0x8004100E"

```
RecycleAppPools("myComputerName")

Sub RecycleAppPools(strComputer)

set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//" _
          &  strComputer & "/root/MicrosoftIISv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * From IIsApplicationPool ")

For Each objItem in colItems 
    objItem.Recycle 
Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: Which error message? (number and text matter). Which line raises the error? (number does not suffice). Please [edit] your question an add those essentials...

Comment: `"winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//"` missing `!` and not sure about `"/root/MicrosoftIISv2"` wmi class rightness...

Comment: I added that and still get the same error message

Comment: Maybe \ backslash instead of `/` here `}!\\"` and in namespace definition as well: `"\root\MicrosoftIISv2"`

Comment: Are you sure the `\root\MicrosoftIISv2` namespace is accessible on `"myComputerName"`? I get the same error for `\root\anyFoolish`... Is `"myComputerName"` a server name or is it the same as `"."` or `"localhost"`?